# Capturing Error Data on $stateChangeError AND $stateNotFound

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im trying to setup some angular error logging around ui-router

I'm not getting the events for $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError'...) - or $stateNotFound.

```
app.run(....)
    $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound',
      function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){
        console.log(unfoundState.to);
        console.log(unfoundState.toParams);
        console.log(unfoundState.options);
      })
```

Whats odd is that i am able to acquire the events for $stateChangeStart && $viewContentLoaded.

I would expect this to occur on going from /page to /page/fake where fake has not defined state

I do not set any default handling using otherwise()